# Unable to read objectValue data using "level" query

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartsheet-api

According to the smartsheet API Docs, I should be able to use "level" parameter in my options to get a complex object for Multi-Contact columns.
Unfortunately all I'm getting in return is value and displayValue.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
var options = {
    id: SHEET_ID, //Id of sheet
    queryParameters = {
            include: ["objectValue"],
            level: 1
        }
}

ss.sheets.getSheet(options)
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log(results.rows[args[0]].cells[6])
            })
```

The above code returns:

```
{ columnId: 8746190272522116, displayValue: 'John Smith, Danny Doe' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've verified (using [Postman](http://getpostman.com)) that Smartsheet API does indeed support the scenario you've described. i.e., if I submit this **Get Sheet** request:

`https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/5831916227192708?include=objectValue&level=1`

...then the response does include the complex object for a multi-contact cell in my sheet:

```
{
    "id": 5831916227192708,
    ...
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 5942480978372484,
            ...
            "cells": [
                {
                    "columnId": 3992195570132868,
                    "objectValue": {
                        "objectType": "MULTI_CONTACT",
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "objectType": "CONTACT",
                                "email": "john_doe@test.com",
                                "name": "John Doe"
                            },
                            {
                                "objectType": "CONTACT",
                                "email": "jane_doe@test.com",
                                "name": "Jane Doe"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "displayValue": "John Doe, Jane Doe"
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

However, it looks like the [Smartsheet JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-javascript-sdk) doesn't yet support this scenario.

It's not unusual for SDK updates to lag a bit behind the release of new API features. You might consider logging an issue in the [JavaScript SDK repo](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-javascript-sdk/issues) to request that support for this scenario be added -- or better yet, submit a PR to that repo that adds support for this scenario. In the meantime, you'll need to implement this functionality yourself within your integration (i.e., since you can't rely on the out-of-the-box SDK functionality to provide it at this time).

Comment: Thank you! Did you know that from looking at the SDK?

Comment: Glad I could help. Yes -- I cloned the SDK my machine, opened it in VS Code, and did a global search for the word ***level*** and verified that it doesn't appear anywhere in the SDK source code in this context (i.e., in the context of the **Get Sheet** operation).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the array notations from your `options` definition:

```
var options = {
    id: SHEET_ID, //Id of sheet
    queryParameters = {
            include: "objectValue",
            level: 1
        }
}

ss.sheets.getSheet(options)
            .then(function (results) {
                console.log(results.rows[args[0]].cells[6])
            })
```